# XSD Schema Error : the content model of complex type definition ' anonymous ' is ambiguous while multipal choice

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-validation

XSD Code: getting error- **the content model of complex type definition ' anonymous ' is ambiguous**

```
<xs:element name="data">
            <xs:complexType>
                <xs:choice>
                    <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                        <xs:element name="A"/>
                        <xs:element name="B"/>
                        <xs:element name="C"/>
                        <xs:element name="D"/>
                        <xs:element name="EE"/>
                    </xs:choice>
                    <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                        <xs:element name="A"/>
                        <xs:element name="B"/>
                        <xs:element name="C"/>
                        <xs:element name="D"/>
                        <xs:element name="FF"/>
                    </xs:choice>
                </xs:choice>
            </xs:complexType>
        </xs:element>
```

Comment: This is expected behaviour. You can't have two identical element declarations in the same context. What do you expect to validate? Please add more detail so we can suggest a better solution.

Comment: Appears to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23149300/nested-choice-element-in-xml-schema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<xs:choice>` selects *one* among many. You have nested choices. The parser complains that there is ambiguity because you have repeating elements declared in the neste choices, violating the [Unique Particle Attribution](http://www.w3.org/TR/xmlschema-1/#non-ambig) constraint.

Example: If the first nested `choice` chooses `A`, and the second one also chooses `A`, you will have this illegal situation in your outer `choice`:

```
<xs:choice>
    <xs:element name="A"/>
    <xs:element name="A"/>
</xs:choice>
```

You *can* have *one* nested choice and accept multiple `A` elements, but not two identical element declarations.

Your code will work if you replace the outer `choice` for a `sequence`.

If you add more detail to your question this answer can be improved to show you a better alternative.

Comment: can you please review this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23149300/nested-choice-element-in-xml-schema  i want to solution of this question please help me.

Comment: See the explanation in that page you referred above in the answer by @C-M-Sperberg-McQueen.